# Is there a way to listen for Location settings(GPS) on/off in Cordova/Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, location

I am working on an hybrid app, which needs location to be enabled always. I need to listen for location settings ON/OFF and alert the user if location is turned off.

Comment: [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) allows you to query the current location settings state, but not to listen for changes in state. However, the location settings state can only be changed by direct interaction from the user, so listening in order to alert them to a change they have made seems counterintuitive. Maybe querying  it on app startup/app resume will suffice?

Comment: Thanks for the info Dave. Location is key in this app, if any user unaware of this, disables the location then i need to force them to enable it back. Since i could not find a way to listen, i will start exploring to get it when app startup/app resume . Thanks for the advice again.

Comment: FYI, that is my plugin and I do have plans to add the ability to listen for state changes, but not sure when I'll get around to implementing it. The next month or 2, I'd think... app startup/resume is a reasonable workaround in the meantime. you can also check on a timer e.g. every 5 seconds.